# How to use nested Q_ENUM in other cpp file, not in qml?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to access Q_ENUM of in-class enum from other class. Do I use cpp enum semantic, like className::enumName, to access it?

Do I have to include "A.h" in "B.cpp" to access A's enum?

Is there other ways to access A's enum using Q_ENUM or QT library?

```
// A.h
class A 
{
    enum enum_A
    {
          E_OP_0 = 0,
          ...
    };
    Q_ENUM(enum_A)
};

// B.cpp
void B::changeOption()
{
    // problem: B.cpp cannot identify enum_A
    qml->setProperty("property", QVariant{enum_A::E_OP_0});
}
```

Thanks

Comment: *Do I have to include "A.h" in "B.cpp" to access A's enum?*, yes, but how does the B class know the definition of enum?

Comment: I mean, does qt support accessing q_enum without including "A.h"? like accessing enum in qml. They just register them and use in any qmls.

Comment: C++ is not QML, not interpoles characteristics of a script language like QML with a compiled and strongly typed language like C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I have to include "A.h" in "B.cpp" to access A's enum?

That would certainly be easiest!

> Is there other ways to access A's enum using Q_ENUM or QT library?

First of all, for `enum_A` to be registered in the Qt Meta system (and the Q_ENUM() to work), the `A` class needs to either inherit from `QObject` (and have `Q_OBJECT` macro) or have a `Q_GADGET` macro. Or `A` could be a `namespace` and one could use `Q_ENUM_NS()` to register the enum instead.

Typically one does not need to use `qRegisterMetaType<>()` on enums, but having done so then this "stupid trick" will work (I have no idea why anyone would go to the trouble, but whatever):

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

class A
{
    Q_GADGET
    public:
        enum enum_A {
            E_OP_0 = 0
        };
        Q_ENUM(enum_A)
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Register the enum type. Here we have to have/know class A declaration.
    qRegisterMetaType<A::enum_A>();  

    // The code below could be elsewhere and not include "class A" header/declaration. 
    // We only need to know the full name of the enum at this point.

    const int enumType = QMetaType::type("A::enum_A");  // The registered type ID.
    // Get meta object of the class/namespace which owns the enum
    const QMetaObject *metaObj = QMetaType::metaObjectForType(enumType);
    if (!metaObj) {
        qWarning() << "Could not get the meta object for enum type.";
        return 1;
    }
    // Index of enum within the meta object data
    const int enumIdx = metaObj->indexOfEnumerator("enum_A");
    // And finally meta data about the enum itself
    const QMetaEnum metaEnum = metaObj->enumerator(enumIdx);

    qDebug() << "Enum name:" << metaEnum.name() << "\n" <<
                "Key count:" << metaEnum.keyCount() << "\n" <<
                "Name of first key:" << metaEnum.key(0) << "\n" <<
                "Value of E_OP_0:" << metaEnum.keyToValue("E_OP_0");

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Enum name: enum_A
>   Key count: 1
>   Name of first key: E_OP_0
>   Value of E_OP_0: 0